# Remove emoji or smiley characters in SQL Server ntext column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a mobile chat conversation text area which is stored in `ntext` data type in SQL Server 2008. I am doing some process character by character. I need to do something I do not know to pass these kind of emoji characters. Should I eliminate them or collate to different collation or encode to different char-set. My table's collation type is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`. I need something like this:

```
IF(SUBSTRING(@chat_Conversation, @i, 1) = 'Emoji')
    CONTINUE;
```

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: ok @marc_s thanks for the warning but do u have any idea about the question asked above?

Comment: With `ntext`, trying to do anything gets really messy and hairy since most of the usual string functions **do not work** on a `ntext` columns ---> upgrade first, *then* do your work

Comment: SQL Server has no problems handling Unicode.  What's your *actual* problem? DId you try to pass Unicode text as ASCII perhaps? Or store it in ASCII fields like `varchar` or `text`? Did you use string concatenation to create the query?

Comment: Why are you trying to remove emojis in the first place? The database doesn't care. SQL Server 2008 R2 handles them just fine. I know, I have a database with user comments

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just want to ignore emoji characters.

Comment: @cihata87 *why* do you want to "just ignore" a specific type of character? There is no storage problem or querying problem involved. It would be a *lot* easier to clean the text during presentation. T-SQL doesn't have regex functions, much less matching against specific Unicode classes. You'd have to check and replace every single emoji character explicitly. C# regular expressions or the Char class do work with character classes or ranges

Comment: @cihata87 to you want to remove emojis from strings or filter out entries that contain emojis? Or filter out entries that contain only a single emoji? Pattern matching in SQL is performed with `LIKE`. You just need to write the proper pattern

Answer (score 2):

As a first guess I'd suggest to place an `N` in front of your literal

Compare the results:

```
SELECT  ''
      ,N'';
```

The result

```
ExtASCII    Unicode
??
```

Without the `N` the literal is read as *extended ASCII*, unknown characters are returned as question marks. With `N` you are dealing with `UNICODE` (to be exact: `UCS-2`)...

### UPDATE

As pointed out in comments: **Do not use `NTEXT`!**

`NTEXT`, `TEXT` and `IMAGE` are deprecated for centuries! These types will not be supported in future versions!

Convert all your work (columns, variables...) to

- `NTEXT` -> `NVARCHAR(MAX)` (covering `UCS-2` characters)
- `TEXT`  -> `VARCHAR(MAX)`  (covering extended ASCII, depending on `COLLATION` and *code page*)
- `IMAGE` -> `VARBINARY(MAX)` (covering `BLOBs`)

### Hint

If you are dealing with *special characters* like foreign alphabets or emojis you should always use the `N` with literals and with types...

Comment: SQL Server supports UTF16LE for some time now, not just UCS-2. There should be no need to remove the emojis

Comment: @Shnugo how can I put N literal beginning of the any variable?

Comment: @cihata87 Just type it there: `SELECT N'Some literal'`. The `N` before the quotes tells SQL Server to read the following as unicode...

Comment: @Shnugo 2K8R2 works with Emojis. I have a table with user comments, including emojis on such a server. Ironically, it was Rails on an older Debian that couldn't work, since it uses dynamic SQL instead of parameters. And *that* Debian had trouble with the emoji range. The Rails guys even tried to persuade me it was a SQL Server problem ...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Cannot test this at the moment, thx for the input! I'm pretty convinced, that this issue is bound to a missing `N` in front of literals. But you are right: There should be no need at all to bother about emojis...